# Website on Ubuntu 20.04 will not show to public

Tags: domain-name-system, wordpress, apache2, ubuntu-20.04

I'm facing a strange issue, at least to me, that I can't crack. My domain is fully propagated according to whatsmydns.net:

[whatsmydns.net report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl4h3.png)

Yet dig won't give me an ip:

> ; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> defactocannabis.com
> ;; global options: +cmd
> ;; Got answer:
> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: **SERVFAIL**, id: 5692
> ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
> ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
> ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
> **;; QUESTION SECTION:
> ;defactocannabis.com.       IN  A**
> ;; Query time: 284 msec
> ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
> ;; WHEN: Tue Mar 15 01:26:04 +04 2022
> ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 48

I checked with my registrar (Namecheap) and they told me everything is okay on their end.

netstat -taupen | grep LISTEN reports:

> tcp  0 0 127.0.0.1:6379  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN  114 36844 3300/redis-server
> tcp  0 0 127.0.0.53:53   0.0.0.0:* LISTEN  101 21112 686/systemd-resolve
> tcp  0 0 0.0.0.0:22      0.0.0.0:* LISTEN  0   24658 815/sshd: /usr/sbin
> tcp  0 0 127.0.0.1:3306  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN  113 25942 884/mysqld
> tcp6 0 0 ::1:6379   :::* LISTEN 114  36845      3300/redis-server 1
> **tcp6 0 0 :::80**      :::* LISTEN      0          68578      8381/apache2
> tcp6 0 0 :::22      :::* LISTEN      0          24670      815/sshd: /usr/sbin

So I can see the server is listening on port 80 for ipv6, but I can't see it mentioned for ipv4.

I've tried disabling both the cloud firewall and UFW (both are the same). This is UFW:

> 22/tcp                     ALLOW       5.226.139.148
> 25/tcp                     ALLOW       5.226.139.148
> **80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere**
> **443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere**
> 443/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
> **53                         ALLOW       Anywhere**
> 80/udp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
> 3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere
> 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
> 443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
> 443/udp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
> 53 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
> 80/udp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
> 3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

I honestly can't figure out what's wrong. If I go to the ip address (http://78.141.209.186/) it's working perfectly. My DNS propagated yesterday, but I still can't get dig to report the appropriate IP or my browsers (Chrome, Chromium, Firefox) to display the page.

**Further Information:**
Earlier today I booted to my live usb and tried going to the website by domain name in firefox, and it worked. So I thought it must my OS (after about an hour of learning to flush DNS caches, etc). I reinstalled the OS. Now it still isn't working! I reset my router. No go. I tried four different VPN nodes. Nothing.

My website simply will not resolve using the domain name. Only the IP. I also tried changing the settings in WordPress from http://78.141.209.186 to http://defactocannabis.com. Only the IP works.

I would really appreciate assistance solving this problem because it is beyond my technical knowledge, and I don't know what to do anymore.

**Note**
The other thing is when I type http://78.141.209.186 into Firefox, it automatically changes to my domain name and I get the error the website can't be found...

Answer (score 1):

`SERVFAIL` means fatal DNS error, and can happen for DNSSEC related errors.

However a good troubleshooting tool like DNSViz, shows no problem with your DNS settings, see https://dnsviz.net/d/defactocannabis.com/Yi_Bhw/dnssec/

All 3 major public DNS resolvers have no issues resolving your name, see:

```
$ for x in 1 8 9 ; do echo $x ; dig @$x.$x.$x.$x defactocannabis.com. A +short ; done
1
78.141.209.186
8
78.141.209.186
9
78.141.209.186
```

Other web related checking tools have no issues either to load your website, see https://shotsherpa.com/adventure/622fc274a3a7405a1349a3b9

So your problem is really a local DNS configuration error somewhere.
Your `dig` output shows `127.0.0.53` which is typically the IP address used by `systemd-resolved` DNS server so you will need to check its status and log. And do a local `dig` query using another nameserver and you will see things work.

PS: there is no DNS propagation, that never existed despite all bad documentation saying so. If you query authoritative nameservers the changes are visible immediately. As for recursive nameserver, they are bound by the TTL and the whole flow is not top down (which would have been a propagation) but only recursive nameservers fetching new data when the TTL expires.